# Python Prediction

Tags: python, csv

I can't get the program to work. I want the program to make a prediction for which Wheat Variety it is according to the user's input. However, I get index out of range result again. I was thinking maybe it has something to do with the return.

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd                                                                             
import numpy as np                                                                              
import os                                                                                       
import csv                                                                                      
import sys                                                                                        
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split                                              
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB                                                         
with open('example.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

next(readCSV)
Wheat_Varietys = []
id = 0
for line in readCSV:
    area = line[0]
    perimiter = line[1]
    compactness = line[2]
    kernel_length = line[3]
    kernel_width = line[4]
    assymetry_coeff = line[5]
    groove_length = line[6]
    Wheat_Variety = line[7]

    Wheat_Varietys.append({ 'id': id,
    'attributes': 
        {
        'area': area,
        'perimiter': perimiter,
        'compactness': compactness,
        'kernel_length': kernel_length,
        'kernel_width': kernel_width,
        'assymetry_coeff': assymetry_coeff,
        'groove_length': groove_length,
        'Wheat_Variety': Wheat_Variety,
    }})
    id+=1                                                                                     
    whatArea = input('What area do you wish to enter?')                                               
    whatPeri = input('What perimiter do you wish to enter?')                                          
    whatComp = input('What compactness do you wish to enter?')                                        
    whatKerL = input('What kernel length do you wish to enter?')                                      
    whatKerW = input('What kernel width do you wish to enter?')                                      
    whatAssym = input('What Assymetry Coefficient do you wish to enter?')                           
    whatGroove = input('What Groove Lenght do you wish to enter?')


    wheat_dataset = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
    wheat_data_cols = wheat_dataset[['area', 'perimeter', 'compactness', 
    'kernel_length', 'kernel_width', 'assymetry_coeff' , 'groove_length']]
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(wheat_data_cols, 
    wheat_dataset['Wheat_Variety'], train_size = 0.8, test_size = 0.2, 
    random_state = 0)
    nb = GaussianNB()
    nb.fit(x_train, y_train)
    def predict_wheat_classification(whatArea, whatPeri, whatComp, whatKerL, 
          whatKerW, whatAssym, whatGroove):
          x_new = np.array([[whatArea, whatPeri, whatComp, whatKerL, whatKerW, 
          whatAssym, whatGroove]])
          prediction = nb.predict(x_new)
       return prediction[0]

    print(predict_wheat_classification(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

and here is the CSV

[example.csv](https://pastebin.com/NTxWCHx4)

Comment: It might be an issue from pasting the code, everything in between `def get_variety(line)` and the return statement (including the return) needs to be indented. The index out of bounds error happens, because you are passing a list of 7 elements to the function and try to access element 7 in the input array. The index only goes from 0 to 6 in the last line. Since you skipped `line[1]` in `get_variety`, i guess you can just change `line[2]` to `line[1]` and do the same for all the following indizes.

Comment: @CodingClown Yeah, I didn't see that I'm already tired haha. Anyways, I just did fixed the index, but it's still out of bounds.

Comment: In what line exactly? Can you paste the error message please?

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d07bd2787c7c> in <module>
     65 
     66 
---> 67 print(get_variety([15.26, 14.84, 0.871, 5.763, 3.312, 2.221, 5.22]))

<ipython-input-4-d07bd2787c7c> in get_variety(line)
     59 
     60     data = np.array(
---> 61     [[line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7]]])
     62     prediction = predict(data)[0]
     63 

IndexError: list index out of range 

This is the error message.

Comment: @CodingClown the error starts in def get_variety(line): what I want to do is get a prediction of the user input according to the example.csv. Then the prediction model will state which wheat variety it is.The error message is index out of range again.

Comment: `np.array( ---> 61 [[line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7]]])` tells me you try to use `line[7]` still. This does not exist. The array you pass to get_variety, is only 7 elements long, so there are only `line[0]` until `line[6]`. In order to access `line[7]`, you need to pass a list of at least 8 elements to the function.

Comment: @CodingClown Did that and now I have a new error message which is 'name 'predict' is not defined' which means there is something wrong with my prediction model. I don't know how to do this anymore hahahha.

Comment: as far as I can see, you neither import this function, nor define it. I assume you wanted to use GaussianNB. Here is an example of how it works: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

Comment: @CodingClown Thank you so much. I have successfully print out the prediction, but do you have any idea on how to put out the actual percentage of the prediction?

Comment: What do you mean? What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: @CodingClown I have already edited the code. The current program I made displays the 'prediction' according to the users input. However, I want to add the actual percentage of the prediction and add accuracy, but I don't quite understand that part.